# How to take n spaced input for multiple lines in java?

Tags: java

11 22 33

44 54 63

73 53 24

I am unable to take input in this format in java.
I am comfortable with n spaced input for single line but am unable to take n spaced multiple line input used in competitive coding.
Can anyone provide me an easy solution to it.

Comment: Could you please format the input in a way so that we can see the individual lines?
Note that this is a Q&A site and not a code writing service. See also how to [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `Scanner` for this purpose:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class GetInput {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int[][] numbers = new int[3][3];

        for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {    //Iterating over the lines - in this case the user has to enter 3 lines
            for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {    //User has to enter 3 numbers per line
                numbers[i][j] = scan.nextInt(); //Scans the next int. It is not a problem that you don't press enter after each number
            }
        }

        //Output - just to test if all went correct
        for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                System.out.print(numbers[i][j] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: In competitive coding we can not print anything other than the sample output given. So in such a case taking input with a space normally is not possible. We can print only the output nothing else neither space or message nothing. So can you provide me with a such solution that is in the context to competitive coding.

Comment: Just edited my answer. Does that answer your question?

Comment: Yes, solved thank you very much. But one more thing that if we are using BufferedReader instead of scanner, then taking input in the required format does gives an error.In that case, If we are taking a single input per line then only it is giving the answer.

Comment: The BufferedReader is not working in the same way. I suggest asking a new question about that topic.